# How to invoke the base method of a dataview delegate

Tags: acumatica

I have a PXGraph with a data view delegate I want to override so I can add a a few more custom filters to the datas displayed on the grid.

I know how I can override and totaly replace the base delegate, but I dont know how I can execute the base logic of the dataview first, then add my filter to the result.

So the result I want to achieve is :

```
    [PXOverride]
public virtual IEnumerable details()
{
   var records = Base.details();
   return records.Where(...);
}
```

I tried just copying the whole original dataview delegate but it calls a lot of privates members of the base graph so i'd have to copy all these members as well and it leads to a lot of ugly duplication in the code.

Edit : my problem is mainly that I can't call Base.details() because the details dataview delegate is declared as protected.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at T200.  It has an example.  In your case, in your data view delegate, you should define a new BQL statement which matches the query of your main view.  Perhaps you should not include any where statements, since you will add them a little further.

```
PXSelectBase<YourDAC> query = new <PXSelectReadyOnly<YourDAC,Where<...>.select(yourParams)
```

Further in your delegate, you can add additional where clauses using WhereAnd...So in your case, you add a filter to the query object like

```
query.WhereAnd<Where<SomeDAC>
```

Finally make sure your delegate returns the iterator.  So you can call

```
return query.Select()
```

That query will execute with your custom filters you added.
Hope this helps

Comment: I have looked into the T200 but I couldnt find where they show how to call the base delegate in order to keep it and just add filtering conditions. Your solution works fine if I just want to add a delegate to a dataview, my problem is my base class already has a dataview delegate, and I want to just add filtering conditions on the result of this delegate, without repeating the code for the base delegate.

Comment: I have override the DataView in my child Extension Graph, DAC has selected property, But when i select(checked) it and try to do operation using selected property then always getting as false, how may get selected true if those are selected from UI? I have override shipment ShipmentScheduleSelect query in my child Graph and always getting as false evan i select it.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. The only thing left is to convert the IEnumerable collection to a List. You need to do this because Linq Where method doesn't operate on IEnumerable collection.

Here is an example calling Customer Payment Methods screen base details delegate and filtering the results using Linq:

```
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class CustomerPaymentMethodMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerPaymentMethodMaint>
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable details()
        {
            List<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail> records = Base.details().RowCast<CustomerPaymentMethodDetail>().ToList();

            return records.Where(record => record.Value == "Bob");
        }
    }
}
```

Results without the additional delegate filter:
[image]

Results with the additional delegate filter:
  [image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, my problem is the Base.details() method is protected in my case, so I just can't call it like that. I'll add this information to my question.

Comment: You can only call a parent class protected method if the class your calling it from inherit from the parent. Graph extensions aren't children of the base graph. Graph extensions are children of PXGraphExtension<T> where T is the base graph type. Because of that it's not possible to call a protected member of the base graph from a graph extension. Also calling the public DataView of the delegate method from the extension delegate ain't gonna work because calling the base delegate will call the child delegate causing an infinite loop.

Comment: So I have to duplicate most of the base class, it's quite ugly from a DRY principle. I dont really get why they declared this delegate as protected. thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's how it is. I think it might be possible to extract the BQL query from the base DataView and re-execute it with PXView but there's little to be gained doing that as it is also re-implementing the base method.