# Override base query in child graph is not calling

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to override the Base DataView (bql) in my child Dac, but doesn't look like it doesn't override by child graph.

```
 public class BaseBLC : PXGraph<BaseBLC, DAC>
{
    public PXSelect<DAC> Objects;
}

public class BaseBLCExt : PXGraphExtension<BaseBLC>
{
    // Overriding using this, but look like it doesn't 
    public PXSelectOrderBy<DAC, 
               OrderBy<Asc<DAC.field>>> Objects;
}
```

I am referring below link, am i doing anything wrong, I am trying to override shipment graph query and want append my own condition, how may i do this, One point is BaseData view is using current in query for filtering record.

Any help?

https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/(W(10))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=b1faf924-c742-4eb2-9a88-0fe299cf6137

Comment: Check out this answer by Hugues Beauséjour. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749492/how-to-invoke-the-base-method-of-a-dataview-delegate/52750993#52750993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code help to override the base DataView.

```
public class BaseBLCExt : PXGraphExtension<BaseBLC>
{
    public PXSelectOrderBy<DAC, 
               OrderBy<Asc<DAC.field>>> Objects;
}

 public class BaseBLCExtOnExt : PXGraphExtension<BaseBLCExt, BaseBLC>
{
    protected IEnumerable objects()
    {
        return PXSelect<DAC>.Select(Base);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have override the DataView in my child Extension Graph, DAC has selected property, But when i select(checked) it and try to do operation using selected property then always getting as false, how may get selected true if those are selected from UI?